Remove other data types except numbers from an array using javascript
Assume I have an array like this arr = [1,2,2,3,3,null,false,undefined] how to remove duplicates and  other data types and keep only unique numbers ? I have tried below `


let originalArray = [1,2,2,3,3, null,false,undefined];
let newArray = [];
let set = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
    if(!set.has(originalArray[i]) && typeof originalArray[i] === Number ) {
    
   newArray.push(originalArray[i]);
       set.add(originalArray[i]);
     
    } 
}
console.log(newArray);



the above code output comes as empty array.
I have tried using typeof but it does not work. Is there any other way or approach to this ?

typeof operator returns a string. not Number just 'number'

I have tried using typeof be sure to debug what you're getting rather than make assumptions on the return value, eg console.log(typeof originalArray[i])

Can use .filter((value, index, array) => typeof value == 'number' && array.indexOf(value) == index) on the array. Typeof checks if its number and indexOf returns first index of occurence and matches to current index of item. Second occurence will have different index.

Set will already be unique, so no need for an additional heck if it's unique

typeof returns a string, so you shouldn't be comparing with the Number function. You can additionally simplify your code with Array#filter and spread syntax.


let originalArray = [1,2,2,3,3, null,false,undefined];
let res = [...new Set(originalArray.filter(x => typeof x === 'number'))];
console.log(res);




If you have a set, you don't really need to keep the other array as well:
const set = new Set(
  array.filter( item => typeof item === 'number' )
);

But if you need it to be converted back to an array, you can do that at the end:
const newArray = Array.from(set);


Below are a few ways to return a new array of unique numbers, the last example mutates an array. Details are commented in example.


// For demo purposes
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

// The result should be [1, 2, 3]
const A = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, null, false, undefined];

/**
 * All examples will filter number with:
 *   typeof x === "number"
 */

/**
 * .filter() returns a new array of true values.
 *   [...new Set()] 
 * A Set returns an object of unique values,
 * the spread operator: ... converts the Set into an array.
 */
const B = [...new Set(A)].filter(x => typeof x === "number");
log(B);

/**
 * .flatMap() returns a new flattened array of values:
 *   ex. [[1, 2], 3, [4]] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
 * A ternary operator is used to return numbers:
 *   typeof x === "number" ? x : []
 * is exactly like:
 *   let z;
 *   if (typeof x === "number") {
 *     z = x;
 *   } else {
 *     z = [];
 *   }
 * All returned empty arrays: [] are flattened leaving only
 * the numbers in the new array. The following does the same thing:
 *   Array.from(new Set()) = [...new Set()] 
 * which is they both covert a Set object into a new array.
 */
const C = Array.from(new Set(A)).flatMap(x => typeof x === "number" ? x : []);
log(C);

/**
 * .reduce() can return unique values by initializing the 
 * accumulator (ex. acc) as an array and searching for dupes
 * within the accumulator with:
 *   acc.indexOf(x) == -1
 * and adding numbers to acc with:
 *   acc = acc.toSpliced(acc.length, 0, x);
 * The empty array: [] at the end is the initial array acc is
 * assigned as.
 */
const D = A.reduce((acc, x) => {
  if (typeof x === "number" && acc.indexOf(x) === -1) {
    acc = acc.toSpliced(acc.length, 0, x);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
log(D);

/**
 * This is a for...of loop that filters unique values with:
 *   !E.includes(x)
 * This will return false if the array already has value x. This example
 * does not result in a new array, .push() mutates (or changes) arrays.
 */
let E = [];

for (let x of A) {
  if (typeof x === "number" && !E.includes(x)) {
    E.push(x);
  }
}
log(E);




You can use filter to get only number values then dedupe it with spread syntax and a new Set

filter returns a new array of the filtered items
The Number method returns a Boolean truthy value. In this case, it only filters numbers
Set creates an object of unique values so we need to wrap it in square brackets to cast it to an array.
The ... is spread syntax which extracts the object keys and inserts them into an index in the array

const originalArray = [1,2,2,3,3, null,false,undefined];
const filtered = originalArray.filter(item => Number(item))
const unique = [...new Set(filtered)]

console.log(unique) // [1, 2, 3]


The Number method returns a Boolean value - That's not right, it returns a number. This wouldn't work if your array had a string like "1"  or a value  like true

The filter filters on a boolean, if you return Number(item) (as in this code) then it returns a truthy value, so will work in this very limited use-case provided by OP.  It won't work if item == 0 or if item == "1"

good catch on the 0 value.  that's why it's important to write tests. I'll take the down vote on this one.
